# pass a tibble row to a named function as unlisted named vectors, including list-columns

Tags: r, function, dplyr, purrr

I'd like to pass a one-row tibble/dataframe, `foo_tibble`, to `foo_func` and have each column of `foo_tibble`, including list-columns, be an unlisted vector when referenced inside of `foo_func` by the name of the column.

The closest I've gotten is with the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo_tibble <- tibble(varr = list(c("A", "B")),
                     var2 = list(c(1, 2, 3)))
# actual case has many more variables which need to be referenced by name in foo_func()

foo_func <- function(...) {
  with(..., {
    print(varr)
    is.list(varr)
    # various arbitrary operations involving different columns here
    })
}

foo_tibble %>%
  foo_func()
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A" "B"
#> [1] TRUE
```

But here `varr` is recognized as a list (length 1) instead of a plain vector. I don't want to have to put `unlist()` around every column name when I use it.

I know one way to accomplish what I want is with an anonymous function inside `pmap()` like so:

```r
foo_tibble %>%
  pmap(., ~with(list(...), {
    print(varr)
    is.list(varr)
  }))
#> [1] "A" "B"
#> [[1]]
#> [1] FALSE
```

I use this type of construction often, such as when I need to iterate over many rows. But in my present situation I only need to do this with one row at a given time and I'm looking for something simpler. I don't think `pmap()` should be necessary in this situation since I am not iterating.

I suspect I am missing something very simple.

Comment: It's a hassle, and inelegant, to put `unlist()` around every variable reference. In my actual case, there are many variables. Same with `[[]]`.

Comment: What it the actual desired output. if you use `dplyr::rowwise()` they don't look like lists: `foo_tibble %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(is.list(varr))`

Comment: desired output would be that `is.list(varr)` returns false inside `foo_func`.

Comment: @RonakShah yes.

Comment: why is `unlist` not required in the `pmap` construction? I guess I was hoping to replicate that behavior, less verbosely.

Comment: I *think* you're probably after `unlist(data, recursive = FALSE)` (or `purrr::flatten()`).  `foo_func <- function(data) with(unlist(data, recursive = FALSE), {print(is.list(varr)); print(is.list(var2))} )`

Comment: @27ϕ9 this seems to work. I could have sworn this was one of the first things I tried, and it didn't work. I must have misplaced a parenthesis. Feel free to post as an answer.